# BiometricDialog in Android P causes Memory Leak

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

I have implemented `Biometric` Dialog for `FingerPrint` Authentication in my App.
I have borrowed the code from the following medium post

[FingerPrint Authentication](https://proandroiddev.com/5-steps-to-implement-biometric-authentication-in-android-dbeb825aeee8)

I keep getting memory leak. Following are the screenshots

[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kgFB.jpg)

[image]

I have nothing called `ReportFragment` in my Project.

Comment: even I am facing the same problem. My AsyncTask has all weakreferences to activity context but still the problem exists.